# (JavaScript) how does event.stopPropagation() work

Tags: javascript

```js
   $('input').click(function(){
        $('input').val('');
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(document).click(function(){
            $('input').val('naam'); 
        });
        
    });
```

```css
input[value="naam"] {
    font-family:  Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif; 
    color: gray;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="Erk_Member">
            Naam:
            <input type="text" name="fname" value="naam" id="Name_Input">
        </form>
```

So as you can see , I used a event.stopPropagation() and it does it work perfectly but I can just paste it and let it stay there while I don't understand it or I could understand it and know when I could use it another time.

So I did some research, on the jQuery website and w3schools and I learned that it's prefenting jQuery from thinking that I clicked the input but also his parent. But I stil don't know how it makes this code work.

Can somebody explane this to me in a simple way

Comment: For starters, putting an event handler registration inside another event handler is almost always a really bad idea.

Comment: [MDN Defines it as](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) *"Prevents further propagation of the current event."* Means it blocks it from traveling up the DOM tree so  it ancestors do not see the event.

Comment: There is nothing in your HTML that makes an event.stopPropagation necessary.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on something in a webpage, that's an event. By default, events propagate "upwards" through the DOM tree, until it reaches a DOM object which contains a handler for that particular kind of event.

This means that there can potentially be MULTIPLE handlers for an event in a DOM structure. e.g. consider the case of a button inside a link:

```
<a href="gohere.php"><button onclick="dosomething()">click me</button></a>
<script>function dosomething() { alert('clicked!'); }</script>
```

In normal operations, clicking the button would trigger the button's `onclick` handler and call the `dosomething` function, and you get an alert. But the event will still be "in play", and trickle upwards to the containing/parent `<a>` tag, and count as a click on the link, causing the browser to start loading up `gohere.php`.

`.stopPropagation()` prevents that bubbling action. Essentially it's going all Gandalf on the event: "Though shalt not pass". If `dosomething()` was converted into

```
function dosomething() {
   alert('clicked');
   event.stopPropagation();
}
```

the `click` on the button would stop at that point, and no trigger the `<a>` tag anymore. You'd get the alert, and nothing else would happen.